# Debian 8 - Install lastest version of MySQL

Tags: debian, mysql

After downloading MYSQL APT Repository at

```
http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-5.7/libmysqld-dev_5.7.11-1debian8_amd64.deb
```

I ran the command

```
dpkg -i libmysqld-dev_5.7.11-1debian8_amd64.deb
```

and here is the result

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-server.
(Reading database ... 48773 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-server_5.7.11-1debian8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-server (5.7.11-1debian8) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-server:
 mysql-community-server depends on mysql-common (= 5.7.11-1debian8); however:
  Package mysql-common is not installed.
 mysql-community-server depends on mysql-client (= 5.7.11-1debian8); however:
  Package mysql-client is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
```

Did I do anything wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the `Depends` list inside the `DEBIAN/control` file of the binary package `libmysqld-dev_5.7.11-1debian8_amd64.deb`, then **download and install** the ones your system doesn't have.

**Example**

```
> wget http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-5.7/libmysqld-dev_5.7.11-1debian8_amd64.deb
> ar x libmysqld-dev_5.7.11-1debian8_amd64.deb
> tar xf control.tar.gz
> cat control | grep Depends
Depends: libmysqlclient-dev (= 5.7.11-1debian8)
```

If you have too much uninstalled dependencies, I recommend you to **install** the `GPG key` of that `debian repository` and add the `source` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` as described by the provider of that `binary package`.

**[A Quick Guide to Using the MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/)**

This is the line, that you should add to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or any `.list` file insde `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian jessie mysql-5.7
```

To install the `MySQL GPG Public key` you can run:

```
> gpg --recv-keys 5072E1F5
> gpg --export 5072E1F5 > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/5072E1F5.gpg
```

After running `apt-get update` you should be able to install the package you want using `dpkg -i` and even running `apt-get install libmysqld-dev`

Comment: Could you please provide the exact lines that I need to insert into `/etc/apt/sources.list`? I'm completely dumb at this task.

Comment: have you tried it by typing _sudo apt-get install mysql-server_ ?    You can  Create a file named  _/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list_  and put into it repository entries in the following format:   _deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/{debian|ubuntu}/ {jessie|wheezy|precise|trusty|utopic|vivid} {mysql-5.6|mysql-5.7|workbench-6.2|utilities-1.4|connector-python-2.0}
_

Comment: @Tresdin Yes ↑ :D

Comment: @RameshChand It is also a good option, just note that @Tresdin wants to install `libmysqld-dev`, not `mysel-server`... So @Tresdin could run `apt-get install libmysqld-dev` after installing the `GPG Public Key`, adding the source to any `.list` file inside `/etc/apt/` and running `apt-get update`

Comment: @ncomputers.org I got the error after running `apt-get update`  `GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available NO_PUBKEY 8C718D3B5072E1F5`

Comment: @Tresdin ↑ I've tested it, if it doesn't work, please let me know it and I will keep trying help you :D

Comment: @ncomputers.org I ran `gpg --recv-keys 5072E1F5` and it returned an `keyserver failed` error. I ran it for a second time and it finally works. `dpkg -i` still fails with same error but `apt-get install` works fine. BTW, do you know the reason behind this error? Is it a MySQL APT repo error or a system one? Thanks.

Comment: @Tresdin I didn't know, and thanks to you I know it now, that `dpkg` doesn't install dependencies automatically, so the only solution you would had with `dpkg -i` was to download each dependency, each dependency of its dependencies and install them manually: `dpkg -i dep1.deb dep2.deb pack.deb`. I am a little surprised, because it seems that inside the `MySQL` documentation, there are no clear instructions to install the `debian repository`.... :(

Comment: @ncomputers.org I've found a question that's quite fit with my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139127/how-to-trust-a-apt-repository-debian-apt-get-update-error-public-key-is-not-av. I've checked `debian-keyring` package and it's not installed on my system.

Comment: @Tresdin, Oh wait! I have it neither! Check if you have this `debian-archive-keyring` :D

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue on my servers. Some of my database boxes took the 5.7.11 patch with no issues and others produced the same error you have gotten. Also if this were an upgrade try commenting out any ssl settings in my.cnf before resorting to the below.

I tried all sorts of fixes but the only one that resolved it was to purge all of `mysql` except the data directory.

Backup your data first. Tell it to keep your data dir and have a copy of your config dir under home or off the box. You will need to replace it when finished.

My Fix:

```
su
apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
deluser mysql
apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

Reinstall mysql apt repo:

```
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
#update and install any needed system updates
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
#enter new/same root password
```

You should be good to go.